# How to differentiate Survival probability function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, actuarial-science, integro-differential-equations

$$\phi(u)=\int_0^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^{u+ct}f(x)\phi(u+ct-x)dxdt~~~(1)$$ 
Substituting $s = u + ct$ in the equation 1,
$$\phi(u)=\dfrac{1}{c}\int_u^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda (s-u)/c}\int_0^{s}f(x)\phi(s-x)dxds $$
$$ =\dfrac{1}{c} e^{\lambda u/c} \int_u^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda s/c}\int_0^{s}f(x)\phi(s-x)dxds ~~~(2)$$
We can establish an equation for $\phi$, known as an integro-differential equation, by differentiating equation (2) and the resulting equation can be used to derive explicit solutions for $\phi$. Differentiation gives

$$\dfrac{d}{du}\phi(u)=\dfrac{\lambda}{c}\phi(u)- \dfrac{\lambda}{c}\int_0^u f(x)\phi(u-x)dx ~~~(3)$$

How equation (3) has been derived?

Answer (score 0):

By the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus),
$$
\Theta(u) = \int_u^\infty \theta(s) d s
$$
is a primitive of $-\theta$ when $\theta$ is continuous and the integral exists, so that $\Theta^\prime(u) = - \theta(u)$